# WPF how to bind two observable collections of different but related types using a value converter?

Tags: wpf, data-binding, wpf-controls

I have a custom control with an observable collection(DP) holding a certain type objects. I want to bind it to another observable collection holding a different type objects in my VM. How do I do this?

Should I even be doing something like this?

Edit. Ofcourse the binding should work when elements in the collections are modified on either side.

Comment: If you know how to bind the two different types together, maybe you could create a helper class that subscribes to the `CollectionChanged` event of one of the collections. In the event handler you you keep the collections synkronized and set up the bindings in Add Action and remove in the Remove Action. Depending on your scenario, you may also need to handle Move, Replace and Reset

Comment: This should have been added as an answer. I think that'll work and was toying with the same idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Meleak*'s comment is correct, you should somehow transform one collection into another and sync them. Here is how I did it last time:

View (I've named it `MyControl` below) has property `Items` of type `IEnumerable<Target>`
DataContext has property `Items` of type `IEnumerable<Source>`

```
class CollectionsConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, ...)
    {
        var source = (ObservableCollection<Source>)value;
        var target = new ObservableCollection<Target>(source.Select(/* Convert items somehow /);
        // subscribe to both target's and source's 'CollectionChanged' events
        // and propagate them back and forth to another collection.
        // Propagated events should have converted items of course

        return target;
    }
    ...
}
```

Then in XAML:

```
<MyControl Items="{Binding Items, Converter=CollectionsConverter}" />
```

Regarding converting each item - it can be either generic code which will dynamically determine how to convert `Source` to `Target` and vice versa or it should be a code which will know which exact types it will convert and how to convert them.

Answer (score 0):

ValueConverters don't work the way you're describing, you have to create a new collection by-hand.

This doesn't answer your question directly, but in ReactiveUI (http://www.reactiveui.net), this scenario is quite easy:

```
var derivedColl = someCollection.CreateDerivedCollection(x => new SomeOtherClass(x));
```

Answer (score -1):

Use your custom Converter class implementing IValueConverter

```
    public class ObserverTypeConverter:IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            //return your dependency type from here     
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            //return your view model type from here, this will get fired if your binding is two way
        }
    }
```

Comment: -1 You have not added anything more than what is already in my question.

Comment: Sorry for sounding rude but now you have added something completely pointless. The question is specific to observable collections of different types. I obviously know how to write a value converter. Thats not the point. I am writing a custom control on which every mose click position is recorded in a collection which I want to Pass on to the VM. Hence the observable collection DP in the control.

Comment: Its ok if being rude going to solve your problem ;) ..... I believe you should avoid having collection in your view. otherwise wheenever you modified anything in ui, you need to recreate collection which will trigger binding and converter will convert it back to vm collection... This will be performance overload which lead back to my original question, why do you need to have type specific collection in view?  Expecting a less rude reply this time...

Comment: see my edits in earlier comment. Also you are presupposing that I need to recreate the whole collection.

Comment: This is like whenever u change ui property, recreate ui collection which bound with viewmodel collection through converter. You are aware of role of converter which will recreate vm collection. For second part, when vm collection property changed, u need to subscribe to property changed event of ut vm collection object in ur vm. this event handler will recreate vm collection, which will update ui through converter..... I cant explain beyond this....